# How to use Google Tag Manager in Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-apis-explorer, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm pushing a simple ecommerce object to the Google Tag Manager `dataLayer` on the client side. It's working fine but I need to move this to the server.

I found the [Google API Node.js Client Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) but it's still pretty young and I'm not able to find any working examples.

Has anyone managed to do this? How would I accomplish the following using the google-api-nodejs-client in node.js?

```js
dataLayer.push({
  event: 'purchase',
  user: 'user_1234',
  transactionId: 'trans_123',
  transactionAffiliation: 'Acme Clothing',
  transactionTotal: 11.99,
  transactionProducts: [
    {
      id: '1234',
      sku: 'SKU47',
      name: 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',
      price: 11.99,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need the google API for this or that library. You can just use the [Google Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).

[Here's an example of how they build the call.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#ecom)

So for your datalayer post, it will be something like:

**For the transaction**

```
v=1               // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y   // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=1234          // user_1234.

&t=transaction    // Transaction hit type.
&ti=123          // transaction ID. Required.
&ta=acmeClothing   // Transaction affiliation.
&tr=11.99         // Transaction revenue.
```

**Then the item hit**

```
v=1               // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y   // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=1234          // Anonymous Client ID.

&t=item           // Item hit type.
&ti=123         // Transaction ID. Required.
&in=fluffy pink bunnies         // Item name. Required.
&ip=11.99           // Item price.
&iq=1             // Item quantity.
&ic=sku47      // Item code / SKU.
```